# Visual Studio 2017 cursor odd behaviour

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I might've changed some settings in Visual Studio, but now if I write code like this and then write the comment (for `Elem elem`) and move cursor down, it moves to the same column as it was on the previous line (rather than right after `next`;)

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

typedef string Elem;

class CircleListNode {
 private:
  Elem elem; // the element of the list
  CircleListNode* next;                |//<-where cursor moves 

 public:
  CircleListNode();
  ~CircleListNode();                        
};
```

How would I change it?

Comment: Are you sure, that there is no whitespace characters on this line (spaces/tabs)?

Comment: I googled "visual studio cursor line position" and came up with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34501511/visual-studio-2015-arbitrary-cursor-position-on-empty-line with an answer regarding an option called Enable virtual space. Could that be your issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2015 - arbitrary cursor position on empty line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34501511/visual-studio-2015-arbitrary-cursor-position-on-empty-line)

Comment: I just tested this in Visual Studio and it appears the linked question has the fix for this. I could see this having some use when trying to draw or explain something but not for much else. Note of course the duplicate mentions to change the C# setting but you're writing C++ so you'd obviously change the C++ one

Comment: Yes! Thabk you!